# Unable to install MongoDB Version 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, installation, ubuntu-22.04

I am installing MongoDB on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using the installation instruction from MongoDB official docs at: ([Install MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)).

I tried the commands which were mentioned in MongoDB for importing the public key as follows:

`curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \ sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \ --dearmor`

Then, I created a list file for for the version of Ubuntu as the following:

`echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list`

But when I run update for updating packages to install MongoDB, I get the following errors and warnings.

`W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu <release>/mongodb-org/7.0 Release: \ The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B7C549A058F8B6B E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu <release>/mongodb-org/7.0 Release' \ is not signed. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Answer (score 0):

add the key first,
and don't forget to specify the right version

```
curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).